# Can HSTS be disabled in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, hsts

For pentesting/VA, it is, of course, imperative to always be able to see the HTTP site of a target. If present, HSTS conflicts with this need.

Without using a proxy to address the problem (e.g. Burp), is it possible to natively disable HSTS in Firefox?

Comment: I doubt it. It would run counter to [the *No User Resource*](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797#section-12.1) desire in the HSTS standard.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the "without using a proxy" requirement? Web pentesting without an intercepting proxy would be like trying to write code in Notepad; you could technically do it, but you'd be wasting far more of your time than it would take do download a minimally-proper tool for the task. HSTS can be easily bypassed or suppressed (set the max-age to 0) in a proxy.

Comment: This is a pure Firefox question, not an InfoSec question. I'd ask over on Firefox forums.

Comment: @CBHacking "without a proxy" is no requirement of mine; it was just a way to avoid getting answers that say "you could do this in your proxy". I was simply interested as to whether anyone knew if it could be switched off in the browser.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, "No User Resource" refers to "should not
   be presented with a **dialog**". But we ain't talking about dialogs here, shouldn't the browser provide at least some obscure settings for testers who wish to disable it?

Comment: Introducing the variable "test.currentTimeOffsetSeconds" did not work

Comment: Use Pale Moon. It allows you to override certificate errors for HSTS-enabled sites like normal.

Answer (score 43):

1. Type `about:support` in firefox
2. Click **Profile Folder | Open Folder** which should open your profile folder.
3. Find file called `SiteSecurityServiceState.txt` and open it
4. Find the entry for your site url and remove it. Entry would looks something like - `github.com:HSTS  120 17242   1521194647604,1,1`
5. Make sure for above firefox is closed so that it does not overwrite it.

Firefox stores HSTS entries in this file with their expiration periods. Removing this entry should allow you to hit http url. TO further prevent it you can probably change permission of this file to read only.

More details - [Understanding HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2017/03/understanding-http-strict-transport.html)

NOTE : This will not work for well known sites like google as those lists are preloaded by browsers. Works fine for others. See above link for details.

Comment: A bit clunky but I can confirm this works in Firefox 79.

Answer (score 29):

I was able to disable it by setting `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist` to **false** in about:config

Then, to see the add exception button you may need to refresh the cache doing the 5 steps listed here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/154176

Comment: Does not work on 67.0.2+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: Works on FF 68.0.

Comment: Tested on Firefox 67 and 68. Does not work. -1

Comment: Works on Firefox 71, you might also want to remove the site from your history first by using the "Forget about this site" feature (from the History)

Comment: Works on Linux - Firefox 71. No need to do anything else.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Linux Firefox 72. I tried clearing browser history and restarted Firefox after changing config but no luck

Comment: This did the trick for me! Since I have control over the proxy of the website, FF remembered the HSTS header, even when I removed it at the proxy level, it didn't bothered to check the header existence again. But when I set this flag it checked again, and then allow me to skip the self-signed cert.

Comment: Works on FF 84 on Mac. No other solution worked for me there - even using new profile.

Comment: Worked for me in FF 91.9.0esr on Debian 11.

Answer (score 24):

According to several forums, you can disable HSTS by introducing a new configuration variable. First, go to the Firefox configuration page (about:config), right-click, choose "New Integer", then provide the name "test.currentTimeOffsetSeconds" (no quotes) with a value of 11491200. This should bypass HSTS, although you may also need to clear the Cache and Active Logins in the Clear Recent History dialog (Ctrl-Shift-Del).

This apparently works because of a function called GetPreloadListEntry that checks to see if the current time is less than the next list expiration time; since the time is effectively calculated to be *later* than the expiration time, no check is performed. This effectively disables HSTS checks.

Comment: This does not work on Firefox 45.0.2 for Mac. Check is not disabled.

Comment: Doesn't work on Linux with failfox 46.0

Comment: Works in Firefox 47.0 in Windows if "Forget About This Site" is also used.

Comment: Doesn't work on Linux with Firefox 49.0, even if "Forget About This Site" is also used.

Comment: It does work on Linux with Firefox 51.0.1. To "Forget About This Site" press "Ctrl+h", search for the domain you want to forget (perhaps you need to do that not only on "example.com" but also on "a.example.com", "b.example.com" etc), right-click and select "Forget ..." on all the matches. Maybe you will also require restart.

Comment: working for me in Firefox Quantum 59.0.2 !

Comment: In FF 69.03 x64 on Windows 7, I had to do the following for this to work: 1) The time offset thing mentioned in this answer. 2) Setting network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist to false as mentioned in the answer below (https://security.stackexchange.com/a/195679/55040). And 3) Clear all my browser cache, history, and restart the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If your scenario is that you've accidentally set HSTS on a site you're working on and need to clear it, "Forget about this site" does the trick.